# quarkus-cucumber does not find step definitions

Tags: java, cucumber, quarkus

I'm trying to set up acceptance tests for a Quarkus app, using [quarkus-cucumber](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-cucumber) 0.6.0 (on Quarkus platform version 2.15.2.Final), but it fails to find the step definitions.

My package structure looks as follows:

```
src
  main
    api
    backend
    gui
  test
    java 
      com.example.test
        AcceptanceTest.java
        steps
          BlahSteps.java
          BlubbSteps.java
    specifications
      blah.feature
      blubb.feature
```

The `AcceptanceTest.java` specifies the package for the glue:

```
package com.example.test

@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/specifications",
    glue = "com.example.test.steps"
)
public class AcceptanceTest extends CucumberQuarkusTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runMain(AcceptanceTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the `BlahSteps.java` in that package contains methods for the steps in `blah.feature`. (It also ends up correctly in `target/test-classes`.)

Still, no matter whether I run `mvn clean test` in the terminal (or `./mvnw quarkus:test` after annotating the `AcceptanceTest` with `@QuarkusTest`) or run the test in IntelliJ, it runs the blah feature and tells me:

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:
...
```

Why is it not finding the glue? Am I missing something?

Comment: your ".feature" files has to be in test/resources folder , it is how it shown [here](https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-cucumber/dev/index.html)

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. The problem is not the feature files, they are found; the problem is that the step definitions are not picked up - or I run the tests incorrectly.

Comment: can you provide a small reproducer?

Comment: Yes. Removed some stuff and now it works like a charm: https://github.com/cunger/quarkus-cucumber-example
Thanks for taking the time! :)
The only remaining question now is how to trigger these tests with the maven-surefire-plugin (since they run as QuarkusTests and not QuarkusIntegrationTests). If I run `mvn clean test`, for example, it only runs the API test, not the Cucumber tests.

Comment: @ChristinaUnger have you found a way to trigger them via Maven?

Comment: @TunaYagci Yes, I needed to include the `AcceptanceTest` class in the surefire plugin, see ozkanpakdil's answer. I also updated the example repo, there it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure surefire plugin like below

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/AcceptanceTest*.java</include>
        </includes>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

below you can see how cucumber triggered.

```bash
mintozzy@laptop:~/tmp/quarkus-cucumber-example$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example:quarkus-cucumber-example:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 56, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< com.example:quarkus-cucumber-example >----------------
[INFO] Building quarkus-cucumber-example 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ quarkus-cucumber-example ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/mintozzy/tmp/quarkus-cucumber-example/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.0.Alpha2:generate-code (default) @ quarkus-cucumber-example ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ quarkus-cucumber-example ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.0.Alpha2:generate-code-tests (default) @ quarkus-cucumber-example ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ quarkus-cucumber-example ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ quarkus-cucumber-example ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) @ quarkus-cucumber-example ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.example.test.AcceptanceTestRunner
2023-01-16 20:05:56,769 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) quarkus-cucumber-example 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.15.2.Final) started in 2.091s. Listening on: http://localhost:8081
2023-01-16 20:05:56,771 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile test activated. 
2023-01-16 20:05:56,771 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, cucumber, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]

Scenario: You're still alright   # specifications/everything_is_fine.feature:9
  Given you are having coffee    # com.example.test.steps.EverythingIsFineSteps.you_are_having_coffee()
  And there is a fire around you # com.example.test.steps.EverythingIsFineSteps.there_is_a_fire_around_you()
  When you are still alright     # com.example.test.steps.EverythingIsFineSteps.you_are_still_alright()
  Then everything is fine        # com.example.test.steps.EverythingIsFineSteps.everything_is_fine()

Scenario: You start to feel it   # specifications/everything_is_fine.feature:14
  Given you are having coffee    # com.example.test.steps.EverythingIsFineSteps.you_are_having_coffee()
  And there is a fire around you # com.example.test.steps.EverythingIsFineSteps.there_is_a_fire_around_you()
  When you start to feel it      # com.example.test.steps.EverythingIsFineSteps.you_start_to_feel_it()
  Then panic                     # com.example.test.steps.EverythingIsFineSteps.panic()

2 Scenarios (2 passed)
8 Steps (8 passed)
0m0.893s


[INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.11 s - in com.example.test.AcceptanceTestRunner
2023-01-16 20:05:58,732 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) quarkus-cucumber-example stopped in 0.035s
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.311 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-16T20:05:58Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here is the [full code](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/quarkus-examples/tree/master/cucumber-integration-test).