# quarkus-cucumber returns Connection refused when running cucumber feature file from the Intellij IDE

Tags: java, cucumber, quarkus

I'm trying to run cucumber feature file tests for a Quarkus app, using quarkus-cucumber 0.6.0 (on Quarkus platform version 2.15.2.Final), but it fails to connect to the app.

Using the git project setup solution referenced here: [quarkus-cucumber does not find step definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75081063/quarkus-cucumber-does-not-find-step-definitions/75139225#75139225) I receive the following stack trace:

```
    Step failed
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
        at ..
..
..
    Failed scenarios:
    file:///home/..../quarkus-cucumber-example/src/test/resources/specifications/everything_is_fine.feature:9 # You're still alright

    2 Scenarios (1 failed, 1 passed)
    8 Steps (1 failed, 7 passed)
    0m1.821s
```

When running mvn test from the terminal, it runs successfully:

```
    ....~/..../quarkus-cucumber-example$ mvn test
..
..
..
    2 Scenarios (2 passed)
    8 Steps (8 passed)
    0m0.800s


    [INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.129 s - in com.example.test.AcceptanceTestRunner
```

When I debug and set breakpoints in this method:

```
    public void everything_is_fine() {
        when()
            .get(BASE_URL + "health")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200);
    }
```

and then Evaluate the when() expression, I discovered that the port is -1 rather than 8081.
Hence the connection refused error.
Has anyone else experienced this ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the solution for the benefit of others...

One must edit the run configuration for your feature, and update the Main class to point to your the class that extends CucumberQuarkusTest.